# Does Virtual DOM used by React slows down browser as it maintains 2 copies of DOM in memory

Tags: reactjs, performance, in-memory, virtual-dom

I know that React updates the DOM in batches which makes react pretty fast by skipping whole DOM updation, but I have a doubt that **does maintaining two in-memory representation of DOM makes browser slow**. Suppose if **I open 10 tabs with react apps** so each app will maintains its own copies of virtual dom in memory.

Comment: There are no 2 DOMs. Please, read the [implementation notes](https://reactjs.org/docs/implementation-notes.html)

Comment: In a sense, there are 2 DOMs, at least 2 implementations: https://medium.com/coffee-and-codes/hey-react-what-is-the-virtual-dom-466ec333bf9a